# How to show text in centre of doughnut chart in ECharts?

Tags: angular, echarts

I want to display the sum of all data values in the centre of doughnut chart without using x and y-axis. For doughnut chart, I used this as reference https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=pie-doughnut

As shown in below code, `chartvalueData` and `nameoflabels` both are coming dynamically.

```
this.chartData = {
          tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item',
            formatter: "{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)"
          },
          legend: {
            orient: 'vertical',
            x: 'left',
            data: nameoflabels,
            bottom: 20
          }
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Title',
              type: 'pie',
              radius: ['50%', '70%'],
              avoidLabelOverlap: false,
              label: {
                normal: {
                  textStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                  }
                },
                emphasis: {
                  textStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                  }
                }
              },
              labelLine: {
                normal: {
                  show: true
                }
              },
              data: chartvalueData,
              color: ['lightblue', 'orange','lightcoral','plum']
            }
          ]
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `formatter` option to show custom values in the chart and `position: center` to center align the label:

```
const data = [
  { value: 335, name: 'A' },
  { value: 310, name: 'B' },
  { value: 234, name: 'C' },
  { value: 135, name: 'D' },
  { value: 1548, name: 'E' },
];

// find the sum of all data values
const sum = data.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current.value, 0);

option = {
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Series 1',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['50%', '70%'],
      avoidLabelOverlap: true,
      label: {
        color: '#000',
        fontSize: '80',
        position: 'center',
        formatter: () => {
          return sum; // Use sum variable here
        },
      },
      labelLine: {
        show: false,
      },
      data: data,
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Using suggested solution i can present the required data on center but however if i hover on the center of doughnut, it highlight any section of the doughnut randomly. Is there any way i can avoid hover actions and remove hand cursor icon on center.
I tried using nested-pie but it has its own other problems.

Comment: @money add `silent:true`. Refer: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.silent

Comment: Murli Prajapati, that removes the animation from whole chart. I just want to remove it from center of the doughnut.

Comment: @MurliPrajapati Can you please tell me where from I can get all possible `options` of this pie-doughnut? It would be a great help to me.

Comment: @Arif Here: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the static text in the center, use `title` for the chart instead of `label` for the series.

```
options = {
    title: {
       text: `${sum}`,
       left: 'center',
       top: 'center',
    },
    series: [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
pieChart.dispatchAction({type:'highlight',seriesIndex: 0,dataIndex: 0});

// PieChart Highlight the Large Value
pieChart.on('mouseover',function(e){
pieChart.dispatchAction({type:'downplay',seriesIndex: 0,dataIndex:0});
if(e.dataIndex != index){
pieChart.dispatchAction({type:'downplay', seriesIndex: 0, dataIndex: index });
}
if(e.dataIndex == 0){
pieChart.dispatchAction({type:'highlight',seriesIndex: 0,dataIndex:e.dataIndex});
}
});
//When the mouse leaves, set the current item as selected
pieChart.on('mouseout',function(e){
index = e.dataIndex;
pieChart.dispatchAction({type:'highlight',seriesIndex: 0,dataIndex: e.dataIndex});
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes